# How do I realize C++ for loop about convolution in Python?

Tags: c++, python-3.x, for-loop, convolution

I need your help. The main question is already written in the title.
I want to realize/convert a specific for a loop about convolution from C++ to Python. I should convolute 1D Vectors in discrete time.

Here the code snippet in C++:

```cpp
for ( i = 0; i < sampleCount; i++ )
{
    y[i] = 0;                       // set to zero before sum
    for ( j = 0; j < kernelCount; j++ )
    {
        y[i] += x[i - j] * h[j];    // convolve: multiply and accumulate
    }
}
```

What I have tried so far:

```py
def convolution(self, inputS):
        self = []
        inputS = []
        outputS = []
        for i in range(0, len(self)):
            y[i] = 0;
            for j in range(0, len(inputS)):
                y[i] = inputSignal[j] * self[i-j];

        return convolve(outputS)
```

I am sure that my Python code may be broken and won't be working. That's why I ask this question here.

If you could help me out, that would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you initializing `self,inputS` when you are getting them as arguments.

Comment: "*I am sure that my Python code may be broken and won't be working.*" The only way to be sure is to test it. This being said, it seems you use `y` in Python, which is not declared. Did you mean `outputS`? Also, assigning to `self` might be a bad idea in Python, but I don't know enough about it to be sure.

Comment: Can you post some dummy 1D vectors in the question itself?

Comment: Note that here `y[i] += x[i - j] * h[j];` you may have a problem in the C++ code, as `i - j` can be negative.

Comment: You invert the loop sizes when converting from C++ to Python

Comment: @TechatTheSparksFoundation One 1D vector could be [1,2,3] and the other [0,1,0]. Convolving them should be result in outputSignal = 1.00 2.00 3.00.

Comment: @Damien In that case, values are outside of either signal and should be zero.

Comment: If you read values *outside* the array, values are undefined, not necessary zero

Comment: Yes, I understand that but can you tell me how to code it?

Comment: Perform the addition `y[i] += x[i - j]  * h[j];` only if `i >= j`

Comment: Can you post the whole code? That would help me better.